# 出于考虑 vs。 基于考虑 。 Do Taiwanese say 基于？

Tags: grammar, taiwan

Question for you all. Recently, I've been using a textbook from mainland China. In the textbook, I learned 出于Sth考虑, which means roughly "Out of consideration for ___"

My teacher, who is Taiwanese, corrected me to say "基于Sth考虑"。

I'd be interested - for any native speakers. Which do you prefer to say? Where are you from? (And, if you know, is there a regional difference)?

Thank you!

Comment: I use both. (Mainland)

Comment: I believe both are acceptable and understandable to native speakers. I would say something might out-of-topic, but do helpful for you. Due to the political reason, many Taiwanese are very sensitive to the cultural stuff (like your textbook) from mainland. Your teacher corrected you very likely not because of the grammar reason, but because you are using a text book from mainland.

Comment: Native speaker originally from Taiwan 25 years ago. 基於 sounds more correct to my ears. I do find that my canto and mandarin are more "formal" than native speakers arriving in North America after the 90's.

Comment: 基於 and 出於 sound both acceptable to me (26 years native speaker from Taiwan). The weird part is from the usage of 考慮. I rarely heard someone uses it as a noun, it always uses as verb in Taiwan. In the example you provided, I will prefer 考量 instead of 考慮.

Answer (score 2):

In my view,

"出於" and "基於" are slightly different from each other.

出於: When you are doing something for the sake of a specific group of person. 
You may also use it when you want to express somehow positive or negative things.

基於: It is more formal and neutral. Therefore, use it when you are doing so for official reasons, or when you are not caring a specific group of person. 
You should also use it when you want to keep a neutral stance.

For example: 
**出于**对妻子身体的考虑，他在乡间买了所房子。 
You are caring your wife, which you are expressing positive attitude(I think), so you use 出于.

**基于**保安理由，需要保密。
You are doing it for official reasons, without expressing any feeling inside, so you use 基于.

Answer (score 2):

For those who lives in mainland China when using in daily life, there is no any difference between 基于 and 出于.

Answer (score 1):

have a look of this article:

http://hk.apple.nextmedia.com/supplement/columnist/art/20150903/19279967

both "出於" or "基於" are equivalent of english "based on".

i would prefer "pure chinese", as suggested by the author, or, write in literary chinese.

Answer (score 1):

Ask your Taiwanese teacher which of the following does he prefer:

1. 出于对妻子身体的考虑，他在乡间买了所房子。
2. 基于对妻子身体的考虑，他在乡间买了所房子。

To me the answer is undoubtedly 1, whatever the flavor of Chinese it is.

Again, this depends on the context: `出于` sounds more casual, while `基于` sounds like something you would use in a government report. But also bear in mind that where there is a rule, there are exceptions. Someone could absolutely come out with valid examples totally contradicting mine.

Like 水巷孑蠻 said, both expressions are influenced by English. Many Chinese writing and translation guidebooks warn against such usage. Out of the [26 sentences](http://dict.youdao.com/example/blng/eng/out_of_consideration_for/#keyfrom=dict.main.moreblng) from 有道词典, only 3 are translated to 出于...考虑.

Comment: Is the 对 necessary? It's not in the original question...

Comment: I think it's necessary, and Wang Dingwei's example is incomplete. 出于对妻子身体健康的考虑 maybe clearer.

Comment: @daniel `对` and `身体健康` make the sentence clearer, but in casual conversations, no one would notice if you drop any of them.

Answer (score 0):

Above all, I am a Chinese student from mainland.

In my point of view, firstly,both 出于 and 基于 are correct. Then, which to choose，出于or基于，is based on sth . If it is abstract,such as mood,health,sympathy and so on,maybe you choose 出于 properly. If it is concrete,such as theory,fact,phenomenon,present situation and so on,maybe 基于 is better.

In fact, there is no clear difference between 出于and基于. They have overlapping range of application. As we Chinese students  learning English, we are always puzzled in that which is correct in this sentence ,in or on? Maybe you English speakers would say,both them are correct,but in this situation,on is better,in that situation,in is better.

Moreover,as for what you mentioned,religion difference. According to my experience,Taiwanese is more traditional,using 基于 maybe more academic from their part. Maybe  出于 is informal.

By the way,出于 is widely used in spoken language and novel, unofficial report. 基于 is widely used in writing language,government report,thesis.

Hope these are useful for you^_^  enjoy Chinese